# SQL exclusion regexp

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, regular-expressions

I have a data extension with a level field based on the subscription level of customers. The fieldcontains 4 options, beginner, intermediate, expert and when they choose nothing it is unspecified(BLANK), it doesn't show anything.

I'm trying to get the beginner field and unspecified only

So far, I've tried

```
WHERE l.Level NOT like '%intermediate%'

AND l.Level NOT like '%expert%'
```

but that only gives me the beginner customers and I also need the ones that have the status unspecified.

I'm trying to use regexp but I'm not confident with the syntax and I get an error

```
WHERE l.level not like REGEXP '^[^intermediate]' 

AND l.level not like REGEXP '^[^expert]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your blank value is `null` so update your first where clause to :

```
WHERE l.Level like '%beginner%'

OR l.level is NULL
```

Comment: if I only do l.level is NULL I get the right data and if I only do l.Level like '%beginner%' I get the right data as well but when I do them together, using AND or OR I get 0 records